# MVC edit complex model ICollection property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller, master-detail

I am using .net MVC 4 and EF 5.
I have a model with Master detail structure like:

```
    public partial class Master
    {
     public int IdMaster { get; set; }
     public String MasterName {get; set;}

     public virtual ICollection<Detail> details { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Detail
    {
     public int IdDetail { get; set; }
     public String DetailName{get; set;}

     public virtual Master master { get; set; }
    }
```

I have created a "Create" view where I have input fields for Master and js code
for adding Detail rows. Everything forks perfectly, "Create" HTTP POST Controller binds everything perfectly and code:

```
    context.Master.Add(master);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

inserts both in Master and Detail tables.

But when I do the Edit post... my debuger tells me that the binding is good, I have some updates on some Detail rows and some new rows for example...
but after completing the post, I get only updates of Master table, while Detail is the same as it was before Editing.

Currently, I am using workaround by deliting all details and reinserting them in "Edit" Controler before Editing the master, but I am interesting if there is a soluting where EF can detect this changes and deal with Details...

Update 1:

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Master master)
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          db.Entry(master).State = EntityState.Modified;
          db.SaveChanges();
          -- this updates only the Master table
          -- but my Collection Master.details which has some new and some updated 
          -- element properties does not change in database. 
-- How can EF do adding, deleting and inserting into Details table based on my Collection?????
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: hi can you show the code whehere are you editing the details

Comment: I just do this:

 context.Entry(master).State = EntityState.Modified;
 context.SaveChanges();

Comment: So what you need to do is to first read the same entity from context and apply the updates to spefici property if you want to update certain property you need to update and then set the state modified as you mentioned then it should work .

Comment: I can try to write if you give me 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

With the same enitymodel I am able to update the details . Below is the sample code . Since you have not shared any more code I assume you must have masterid and detail id and then you are updating it .

```
     using (var context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            var master = context.Master.Include(x=>x.details).FirstOrDefault(f => f.IdMaster == 1);
            if(master!=null)
            {
                // hre if you want to update the detail with id detaiid= 1 

                var detail = master.details.FirstOrDefault(d => d.IdDetail == 1);
                if (detail != null)
                {
                    detail.DetailName = "update detail";
                }
                context.Entry(master).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```